Simplest way to implement ports and adapters (aka clean architecture) in springboot
Can the example below be considered as a simple but complete implementation of ports and adapters (clean architecture) in spring boot?
In the presentation layer or controller
@Autowired
SomeService service;

where SomeService is an interface
In SomeServiceImpl
@Autowired
SomeRepository repository;

where SomeRepository is an interface
The whole concept behind clean architecture is that business logic shouldn't care about presentation layer or data access layer. We should be able to write the business layer independent of how other layers are implemented.
The code example above is usually how most developers write spring boot based applications. I am just curious to know from the experts on here, is this standard way of writing spring boot application already in the clean architecture (aka ports and adapters) pattern? Or is there any modification/consideration required in this code example to make it truly clean architecture?

When you say "Clean architecture" do you refer to the book by Uncle Bob/Robert C. Martin?

"Is the practical application of clean architecture, essentially anything more than using interfaces?"  - At the very least, it is "use interfaces" in a specific way.

@StephenC I probably did not ask in the right way. In clean architecture (by uncle Bob), he mentions that the business layer should be agnostic about the presentation and data access layer. Reading DDD, they too talk about this exact same concept in ports and adapters. When you implement it code, I think essentially ports and adapters comes down to what I put above. Wanted to see if I missed anything.

Many confusing things have been written on the topic. Go to the source: Look up videos of talks by Alistair Cockburn who coined the terms “Hexagonal architecture” and “Ports and Adapters”.

Regarding your Question, the key concept is for “driven” parts of your app (right-side of the hexagon) the core (business logic and domain objects) invokes methods on interfaces that are implemented outside the core that in turn accesses databases, message queues, email, etc.  The “driving” parts of your app such as GUI, console UI, Web Services call handlers, or other ways to stimulate your app invoke methods on interfaces implemented within the core.  Simple idea, but it took me much digging to find that said in direct language.

Driving parts (user-interfaces, incoming messages, etc.) → interfaces → [ implementations → business logic & domain objects → interfaces ] → implementations → Driven parts (database engines, message queues, email/SMS/RCS messages, printers, etc.) The brackets here represent the core. (But this is much too broad to be discussed on Stack Overflow, so I’ll stop here.)
